# Refreshing Resolve Data - Ui Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

In ionic I'm resolving my data with the Ui-Router's `resolve` functionality before the controller is initialized. As of now I don't have to `$inject` my `EventService` into the Controller. The `EventService`'s `getEvents()` method resolves the data before the controller is initialized. Everything works correctly this way, but now i'm trying to implement the [Ion Refresher](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionRefresher/). I could easily refresh my `$scope.events` array within the controller, bloating the controller itself, because I would have to `$inject` the `EventService` into the controller, and that also means that every controller that uses the same data will have to contain logic to handle a refresh. What is the best way refresh the data outside of the controller or is that the best way?

**Events State Definition and data resolution**

```
.state('tab.events', {
    url: '/events',
    views: {
    'tab-event': {
        templateUrl: 'views/events.html',
        controller: 'EventsController',
        resolve: {
            events: function (EventService) {
                return EventService.getEvents(); //resolves data before ctrl initialized
            }
        }
    }
   }
})
```

**Events Controller**

```
(function() {
  'use strict'

    angular
        .module('app.events')
        .controller('EventsController', EventsController);

        EventsController.$inject = ['$scope','events'];

        function EventsController ($scope,events) {

            $scope.events = events;

        }

}
)();
```

**Bloated Events Controller - Example**

```
(function() {
  'use strict'

    angular
        .module('app.events')
        .controller('EventsController', EventsController);

        EventsController.$inject = ['$scope','events','EventsService'];

        function EventsController ($scope,events,EventsService) {

            $scope.events = events;

            $scope.refresh = refresh;

            function refresh () {
                clearCache(); //pretend method
                EventsService.getEvents()
                    .then(function (events) {
                        $scope.events = events;
                        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                    })
            }
        }

}
)();
```

Rather than bloating the controller can I refresh this data another way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

call `$state.reload()` which is an alias for:

```
$state.transitionTo($state.current, $stateParams, { 
  reload: true, inherit: false, notify: true
});
```

This will cause all your states to be "re-entered" which fetches the resolves and re-initializes the controllers.

Comment: Upvote, because after posting this I saw your solution, but I tried it and had issues with it. I'm going to try it again and return after reproducing the issue.

Answer (score 4):

I wish a hard refresh, which is basically what a $state.reload() does wasn't the answer.  I too have this issue and would rather be able to call some method that just forces all the resolved data objects to rerun.  The reload causes a page refresh, which causes nasty UI artifacts.